# Adding date field with case statement leads to missing expression fault message, how to solve?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update r5events e       
set         
 e.evt_udfdate10 =  e.evt_reported +    
  CASE  
    when to char(e.evt_reported, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = ('07/01/2023' ) then 5
  end,
```

tried also to_date instead of to_char

Comment: What should happen to any record where evt_reported <> '07/01/2023' ?

Comment: Do you mean `to_char` ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: BTW, that's a `case` _expression_. (And tables have columns, not fields. And rows, not records.)

Comment: yes, of course should be to_char (instead to char).

Comment: @Jan, to address a user, put a @ before the username, and that person will get a notification.

Comment: @ serg but with to_char, now no fault message "expression" but the field evt_update10 is not filled.

Comment: @NickW when <> '07/01/203' it will be filled with other case statement (looking to day of the week), that's working ok

Comment: @jarlh Program uses oracle 12.0

Comment: `TO_CHAR` not `TO CHAR` and remove the trailing `,`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the missing _ in to_char, the trailing comma at the end will throw an error if that's your full SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should compare date to date, not convert date to string and then compare string to string.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From r5events;

        ID EVT_REPORT EVT_UDFDAT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 07/01/2023             --> add 5 to this date because it is equal to 7th of January 2023
         2 25/12/2022             --> you didn't say what to do if date isn't 7th of January 2023,
                                      so I'm leaving it "as is"
```

Update statement:

```
SQL> update r5events e set
  2    e.evt_udfdate10 =
  3      e.evt_reported + case when e.evt_reported = date '2023-01-07' then 5
  4                            else 0
  5                       end;

2 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From r5events;

        ID EVT_REPORT EVT_UDFDAT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 07/01/2023 12/01/2023  --> 5 days added to EVT_REPORTED
         2 25/12/2022 25/12/2022  --> nothing has been added

SQL>
```

---

`update` *might* need to be adjusted if `evt_reported` contains time component different from *midnight*. It would be easier to assist if you posted table description, sample data and desired result.

Comment: Actually I wish to fill a target date for contractual "Target repaired" based on counting from date reported. In normal workday +1day, on friday +3 day because of weekend.
This works ok, based on weekday. (see below).
But now I also wish to add bank holidays too, so f.e. when 07/01/2023 is a bank holiday, then count +5.

Comment: So first:
update r5events e
set 










 
and later 2nd:
update r5events e
set 
   e.evt_udfdate10 =  e.evt_reported +
    CASE
        when to_char(e.evt_reported, 'DD-MON-YYYY') = '07-JAN-2023' then 5
        ... defining more bank holidays ............
    end